Compute relative homology $H_k \left(E_+^n, E_+^n - \left\{0\right\} \right)$, where $E_+^n$ is the upper half space
I am asked to compute the relative homology pair $H_k \left(E_+^n, E_+^n - \left\{0\right\} \right)$ where $E_+^n = \left\{  \left(x_1, \ldots, x_n \right) : x_n \geqslant 0 \right\}$.
and find out that excision theorem doesn't work. I know that $H_k \left(\Bbb R^n, \Bbb R^n - \left\{0\right\} \right) = \mathbb{Z}$ if $k = n$ and vanishes otherwise, therefore I wish an excision cutting off the open lower half of $\mathbb{R}^n$, however, the interior of $\Bbb R^n - \left\{0\right\}$ doesn't contain it and I have no idea about how to continue.
Any advice is appreciated.

Both spaces in your pair are contractible.

@BenSteffan Thanks for you precious hint! Since they are both contractible, I can follow the way of computing $H_k \left( \mathbb{R}^n, \mathbb{R}^n - 0 \right)$ writing down the long exact sequence, but this time $\Bbb H^n - 0$ is also contractible, hence it equals to $\mathbb{Z}$ if $k = 0$ and vanishes otherwise.

@LastingHowling Then you should answer you own question.
